# Implementing to support 24 digits number in asp.net sql server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am implementing an application which contains 24 digits in a textbox for any kind on number.
I am using asp.net 4.5 and sql server 2008r2. So what kind of data type I can use for c# and sql server.

How I can make any calculation with this value like add/subtract some number with this.There is any inbuilt method or function in asp.net.
Can we implement this in java script also.

Comment: [.NET's System.Decimal type has up to 28-29 digits of precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx),

[SQL Server has inbuilt support for types with up to 38 digits of precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187746.aspx); where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks, I will check and can you please give the suggestion for java script also.

Comment: in javascript, numbers are always 64-bit floating point with 52 bits mantissa, 11 bits exponent and 1 bit sign - offering *up to* 15 digits of precision, but noting that not all values can be represented (the classic example being 0.2 + 0.1). Anything you want in javascript would need to be via an additional library that processes the numbers manually, presumably via strings.